# Magento 2 set coupon code

Tags: magento2

I am trying to set an automatically generated coupon code to a Magento 2 quote.
The code I am using is:

```
    $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($post['coupon_code'])->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

The coupon code is being set in the quote but it is not updating when redirected by to the Magento cart page